# Autogenerated sequence diagrams

Tags: c#, sequence-diagram, static-code-analysis, cobol.net

In Ndepend we can get very good dependency diagrams showing which methods are called.

What we have not been able to do is to see in which order the methods are called. For example a method A calls method X and method Y. Then we want to see in the diagram that method X is called before method Y.

Does anyone know if this is possible with NDepend or any other tool?

The code we are analysing is C# and Cobol.net (Ndepend does not analyse the Cobol.Net code, but it does analyse the IL code that was generated from the Cobol.net code)

Comment: No, it is not possible to see order of method calls with NDepend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate can generate sequence diagrams: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee317485.aspx